# Inequality comparison to produces wrong result (sometimes)

Tags: vb6

Our VB6 app has a very strange control-flow problem. It appears that an **inequality comparison of double values is incorrect** sometimes. Furthermore, adding **`MsgBox` calls seems to have some side effects**. And lastly, there are **differences between running in the IDE vs compiled**, and which computer was used to run the compiler.

We cannot reproduce this outside of our app itself, but below are code snippets intended to convey the essential information.

In the first code sample, all values of `d(i)` are `>>> 1` (around 25 million).  So the second branch of the `If..Then` should always be taken. In the IDE, this **is** what happens. In the compiled EXE from one PC the second branch is only ever taken for `i=1` - which is **incorrect**.

**Code block 1:**

```
Dim d(1 to 4) as Double
Dim result(1 to 4) as Double

' ... Some logic to set the value of d goes here

For i = 1 To 4
    If d(i) < 1 Then
       result(i) = 0
    Else
       result(i) = numerator(i) / d(i)
    End if
Next
```

Now, if the code is modified to include `MsgBox` calls... everything works correctly. The second branch is taken all the time (!!)

It is as though the `MsgBox` calls have some side effect which negates the problem noted above.

**Code block 2:**

```
    If d(i) < 1 Then
       result(i) = 0
       MsgBox "Took first branch, d(i) = " & CStr(d(i))
    Else
       result(i) = numerator(i) / d(i)
       MsgBox "Took second branch, d(i) = " & CStr(d(i))
       MsgBox "Some other info"
    End if
```

The exact set of `MsgBox` calls is necessary. If any is eliminated, or if two are combined, the "side effect" does not occur and the inequality for i > 1 is evaluated incorrectly.

---

Further details:

- Setting VB6 to use "no optimizations" when compiling (to native code) will fix the control flow problem.
- Compiling on another PC produces an EXE which does not have the problem. The resulting EXEs are binary different (even accounting for version #s, etc.)
- Running / step tracing in the IDE never reproduces the problem

---

This is all so strange we're starting to think "the compiler is broken".

Could there be an obscure issue in the VB6 runtime or compiler which leads to ... memory corruption? Stack corruption? Or some unknown old cached data polluting the EXE? Bad hardware on the PC that compiles wrong? These are all highly unlikely and yet I'm not sure what else to think.

Any tips to what might be going on would be welcome.

---

**UPDATE**: We're thinking the computer which compiles the incorrectly working EXE may not have VB6 SP6 on it. I'll update again if we confirm this is related.

Comment: I experience a similar issue in my app.  How I get around it is by always rounding before comparing.  For example, `If Round(d(i), 4) < 1 Then`.

Comment: Things that break when optimizations are turned on *can* indicate a compiler bug. What service pack of VB6 is installed on the dev system where it compiles correctly and the one where it doesn't?

Comment: I don't have access to my VB code at the moment, but I wrote a function called something like EssentiallyEqual for just such discrepancies.  I can't remember why, but the rounding suggested by Brian wasn't enough for my situation, although it's obviously always a good idea to round before compare, as he suggested.  For whatever reason, though, perhaps merely to make the code more readable, or because I had to do it a lot, I put it in a function.  It might have something to do with the fact that I give the users of my accounting system the option to use Banker's Rounding or not.